# ASP.Net getting error on "UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, User.Identity.Name);"

Tags: c#, asp.net, directoryservices

I'm trying to deploy an ASP.net webapp - I was originally running the following code:

```
   PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
    UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.Current;

    string displayName = user.DisplayName;
    string username = user.SamAccountName;
```

But I was getting the following error:

*Unable to cast object of type 'System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.GroupPrincipal' to type 'System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal'.*

As suggested in other posts., in IIS I changed the authorisation to Windows Authorisation and changed my code to:

```
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, User.Identity.Name);
```

However, the word Identity is underlined in red and the error reads:

*'SqlDataSource' does not contain a definition for 'Identity' and no accessible extension method 'Identity' accepting a first argument of type 'SqlDataSource' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*

Does anyone have any idea how I can fix this?

The full cs code is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;

namespace Assets
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {



            PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
            UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, User.Identity.Name);


            if ((dgUser.Rows.Count == 0) || (dgUser.Rows[0].Cells[3].Text == "0"))
            {

                Response.Redirect("AccessDenied.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                string admin = dgUser.Rows[0].Cells[4].Text;
                if (admin.ToString() == "1")
                {
                    sidebarConfig.Visible = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    sidebarConfig.Visible = false;
                }
            }

        }

        protected void gvUser_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void users_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

The full aspx code is:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Assets.Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head> 
    <title>
    </title>
    <link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <style type="text/css">
        .auto-style1 {
            width: 100%;
        }
        .auto-style2 {
            margin-bottom: 4px;
        }
        .auto-style3 {
            font-family: "Segoe UI";
            font-size: small;
        }
        .auto-style4 {
            font-family: "Segoe UI";
            font-size: small;
            color: #C84C09;
        }
        .auto-style5 {
            height: 120px;
            width: 120px;
            float: left;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">

<div class="container">

<%--Header--%>  
    <div class="header" style="height:120px; margin-right: 15px; background-color:#3B3B3B;">
      <div class="logo">
        <img alt="Logo" src="Images/logo%20white%20only.jpg" class="auto-style5" />
          <asp:Label ID="lbUser" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
          <br />
          <asp:SqlDataSource ID="User" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:csAssets %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT * FROM [USERS] WHERE ([USERNAME] = @USERNAME)">
              <SelectParameters>
                  <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="lbUser" Name="USERNAME" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
              </SelectParameters>
          </asp:SqlDataSource>
          <br />
          Label</div>
        <%--<img alt="HeaderText" style="height: 110px; "  src="Images/HeaderText4.jpeg" />--%>
    </div>

<div class="body" style="margin-top: 90px;">

<%--Sidebar--%>  
    <div class="sidebar">
        <br />
        <a href ="Default.aspx" class="active" />
            <table style="width:100%;">
                <tr>
                    <td class="sidebarIcons" >
                        <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" Height="25px" Width="25px"  ImageUrl="~/Images/home.png" />
                    </td>
                    <td class="sidebarText">
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;Home
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        <a href="AddNew.aspx" >
            <table style="width:100%;">
                <tr>
                    <td class="sidebarIcons">
                        <asp:Image ID="Image5" runat="server" Height="25px" Width="25px"  ImageUrl="~/Images/edit.png" />
                    </td>
                    <td class="sidebarText">
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;New Record
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </a>
        <a href="Search.aspx" >
            <table style="width:100%;">
                <tr>
                    <td class="sidebarIcons">
                        <asp:Image ID="Image6" runat="server" Height="25px" Width="25px"  ImageUrl="~/Images/case.png" />
                    </td>
                    <td class="sidebarText">
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;View Record
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
        </a>
        <a href="BulkReview.aspx">
            <table class="auto-style1">
                <tr>
                    <td class="sidebarIcons">
                        <asp:Image ID="Image3" runat="server" Height="25px" Width="25px"  ImageUrl="~/images/accept.png" />
                    </td>
                    <td class="sidebarText">
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;Bulk Review
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </a>
        <a href="Configurations.aspx" id="sidebarConfig" runat="server">
            <table id="taConfig" class="auto-style1">
                <tr>
                    <td class="sidebarIcons">
                        <asp:Image ID="Image7" runat="server" Height="25px" Width="25px"  ImageUrl="~/Images/config.png" />
                    </td>
                    <td class="sidebarText">
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;Configuration
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="content" >
        <br />
        <span class="auto-style3">The Assets and Liabilities App split records into three parts:&nbsp; The Header record, Documents and Attributes.&nbsp; Each header Record can have multiple Documents and Attributes. Attributes can also reference saved documents.&nbsp; the field that are availble on the Header Record are dependant on the Asset Type selected.&nbsp; The only required fields for all Asset Types are:&nbsp; Asset Type, Service Owner and Description.</span><br class="auto-style3" />
        <br class="auto-style3" />
        <span class="auto-style4"><strong>New Record</strong></span><br class="auto-style3" />
        <span class="auto-style3">Add a new header Record and the click &#39;Next&#39;, you can then upload multiple documents and add multiple attributes.</span><br class="auto-style3" />
        <br class="auto-style3" />
        <span class="auto-style4"><strong>View Record</strong></span><br class="auto-style3" />
        <span class="auto-style3">From the &#39;My Teams Records&#39; drop down menu, you can select records where the service owner is your team.&nbsp; To find other records, click on &#39;Advanced Search&#39; and search by any of the available fields and click &#39;Search&#39;.&nbsp; this will produce a list of records that meet your search criteria, find the records that you&#39;re after and click View. </span>
        <br class="auto-style3" />
        <br class="auto-style3" />
        <span class="auto-style3">To edit a record click on the Edit icon on the header section, document section or attribute selection, make the amendment and click Save.&nbsp; When Editing the header section you can also review the record, this will change the review date to today&#39;s date.&nbsp; You can also delete the record from here. To add a new Document or Attribute you can click on the relevant Edit icon and then click Add Document or Add Attribute.</span><br class="auto-style3" />
        <br class="auto-style3" />
        <span class="auto-style4"><strong>Bulk Review</strong></span><br class="auto-style3" />
        <span class="auto-style3">This enables you to review multiple records at once. You can either select all of your teams records, or just records that are due for review within the next month or records that are past their review date.&nbsp; By reviewing records you will change the review date to today&#39;s date.&nbsp; You can set how often a record should be reviewed by editing the Review Period field in the header record.</span><br class="auto-style3" />
        <br class="auto-style3" />
        <span class="auto-style4"><strong>Configuration</strong></span><br class="auto-style3" />
        <span class="auto-style3">If you are set up as an Administrator on the app, you can access the Configuration settings.&nbsp; This enables you to add new users, inactivate users, grant Admin privilages or add/edit:&nbsp; Asset types, Contract types, Attrinute Types and Document Types.&nbsp; If you think you should be an Administrator, but can&#39;t see the Configuration option on the sidebar menu, please contact an existing Administrator, or a member of the Business Intelligence Team.</span><br class="auto-style3" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:GridView ID="Records" runat="server">
        </asp:GridView>
        <br />

        <asp:GridView ID="dgUser" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="auto-style2" DataSourceID="userstable" Visible="False" >
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="NAME" HeaderText="NAME" SortExpression="NAME" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="USERNAME" HeaderText="USERNAME" SortExpression="USERNAME" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="SERVICE_AREA" HeaderText="SERVICE_AREA" SortExpression="SERVICE_AREA" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ACTIVE" HeaderText="ACTIVE" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ACTIVE" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ADMIN" HeaderText="ADMIN" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ADMIN" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="userstable" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:csAssets %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [vwUSERS] WHERE ([USERNAME] = @USERNAME)">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="lbUser" Name="USERNAME" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        <br />
          <p>
              &nbsp;</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Many Thanks

Comment: You have a SqlDataSource with an ID of User. That's obviously going to interfere with the User property of the page. Change the ID of your SqlDataSource to something like "UserDS". And really, you shouldn't be using SqlDataSource at all. Those encourage you to put data logic in a web page, where it doesn't belong.

Comment: Thanks @mason how should I be connecting to SQL then, instead of SQLDataSource?

Comment: You have a number of choices. Raw ADO.NET, micro ORMs (such as Dapper), or full ORM's such as Entity Framework. You should research those and pick which one best suits your project and preferences.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old issue, but I found a solution under .NET 6 that others may find usable.

In my case I am migrating from .NET Core 2.2 to .NET 6. And I have encountered the same problem with that same code:

```
var pcontext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "MyDomain");
//Following line fails with a null value on User.Identity.Name
var principal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pcontext, User.Identity.Name);
var givenName = principal.GivenName;//user first name
var lastName = principal.Surname;//user last name
```

Since I am trying to identified the current logged in user, we can accomplish it with the following code:

```
var pcontext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "MyDomain");
var principal = UserPrincipal.Current;
var givenName = principal.GivenName;//current user first name
var lastName = principal.Surname;//current user last name
```